# Pass custom object into Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently in the process of writing a Spring Boot REST API in Java.

I have an entry point as follows:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Starting Spring application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Monolith.class, args);
  }
```

Which successfully creates the controllers.

However, I now have a `RedisCache` object that I wish to pass into these controllers. This `RedisCache` object needs be manually instantiated before the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` (with the correct username, password, address, port and timeout), and I am unsure how to correctly dependency inject this cache into the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a configuration class like such:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  private CacheFactory cacheFactory;

  @Bean(name = "cache")
  public CacheFactory cacheFactory() {
    if (this.cacheFactory == null) {
      this.cacheFactory = new CacheFactory ();
    }

    return this.cacheFactory;
  }

}
```

with the factory looking like:

```
public class CacheFactory implements FactoryBean<Cache> {

  private final Cache cache;

  public CacheFactory() {
    this.cache = new Cache(new RedisSettings(
        "localhost",
        6379,
        "pass",
            10
    ));
  }

  @Override
  public Cache getObject() {
    return this.cache;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Cache> getObjectType() {
    return MonolithCache.class;
  }
```

and injecting the resource by autowiring the constructor in the controller:

```
  @Autowired
  public MyController(Cache cache) {
    this.cache = cache;
  }
```

Unless there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach, it seems to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement interceptor and inject it into the ThreadContext with pre handle

More information:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

Thanks